# Solve for Vector q in q Equals Matrix P Times Vector q

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have a linear algebra problem where I have the problem, the formula and the solution. I would like to understand how to use the formula to get to the solution.

Also, I would like to know whether it is possible to use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) or [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/) (or similar) to solve equations like this.

Matrix:

$$ P =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
.5 & .5 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Formula:

$$q = P^Tq$$

Constraint:

The components of $q$ must add up to 1.

Answer:

$$ q =
\begin{pmatrix}
.2  \\
.4  \\
.4  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I know how to take the transpose of matrix $P$, but I do not know how to solve for $q$.

This question was taken from a slide presented in a university course. This is not a graded assignment.

Comment: The answer is not unique. If $q$ works, so does $\lambda q$, where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary constant. Let me guess, the components of $q$ should add up to one, but you forgot to tell us.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, the components of $q$ must add up to 1. I have edited the question with this constraint.

Comment: You know how to solve $Px=0$ for vector $x$, given matrix $P$, Jacob? Well, $q=P^tq$ rewrites as $(P^t-I)q=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve the system
\begin{align*}
(P^\top - I)q &= \mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf{1}^\top q &= 1,
\end{align*}

or more precisely
$$
\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0.5\\
1&-1&0.5\\
0&1&-1\\
1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}q = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}.
$$